# How to import data from database in jquery datatables

Tags: php, jquery, datatables

I am using jquery datatables and I want to display data which is present in the database.
I used the foloowing code:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
var oTable = $('#example').dataTable( {
    "bProcessing": true,
    "sAjaxSource": "server.php",
    "aoColumns": [
        { "mData": "f_name" },
        { "mData": "l_name" },
        { "mData": "email" },
        { "mData": "active_date" }

    ]
   } );
 } );
```

But I am getting json formatting error saying that json data from server could not be passes. I want to know what file should be passes in  sAjaxSource so that my data from the database is displayed? Right now I am passing server.php which contains my database connectivity code

Help would be appreciated
here is my server.php file.. but I am getting the json formatting error.

EDIT:

```
<?php
/* * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * *
 * Easy set variables
 */

/* Array of database columns which should be read and sent back to DataTables. Use a space where
 * you want to insert a non-database field (for example a counter or static image)
 */
$aColumns = array( 'first_name', 'last_name', 'email', 'active', 'create_date' );

/* Indexed column (used for fast and accurate table cardinality) */
$sIndexColumn = "customer_id";

/* DB table to use */
$sTable = "customer";

/* Database connection information */
$gaSql['user']       = "root";
$gaSql['password']   = "";
$gaSql['db']         = "test";
$gaSql['server']     = "localhost";

/* REMOVE THIS LINE (it just includes my SQL connection user/pass) */
//include( $_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT']."/datatables/mysql.php" );


/* * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * *
 * If you just want to use the basic configuration for DataTables with PHP server-side, there is
 * no need to edit below this line
 */

/* 
 * Local functions
 */
function fatal_error ( $sErrorMessage = '' )
{
    header( $_SERVER['SERVER_PROTOCOL'] .' 500 Internal Server Error' );
    die( $sErrorMessage );
}


/* 
 * MySQL connection
 */
if ( ! $gaSql['link'] = mysql_connect( $gaSql['server'], $gaSql['user'], $gaSql['password']  ) )
{
    fatal_error( 'Could not open connection to server' );
}

if ( ! mysql_select_db( $gaSql['db'], $gaSql['link'] ) )
{
    fatal_error( 'Could not select database ' );
}

/* 
 * Paging
 */
$sLimit = "";
if ( isset( $_GET['iDisplayStart'] ) && $_GET['iDisplayLength'] != '-1' )
{
    $sLimit = "LIMIT ".intval( $_GET['iDisplayStart'] ).", ".
        intval( $_GET['iDisplayLength'] );
}


/*
 * Ordering
 */
$sOrder = "";
if ( isset( $_GET['iSortCol_0'] ) )
{
    $sOrder = "ORDER BY  ";
    for ( $i=0 ; $i<intval( $_GET['iSortingCols'] ) ; $i++ )
    {
        if ( $_GET[ 'bSortable_'.intval($_GET['iSortCol_'.$i]) ] == "true" )
        {
            $sOrder .= "`".$aColumns[ intval( $_GET['iSortCol_'.$i] ) ]."` ".
                ($_GET['sSortDir_'.$i]==='asc' ? 'asc' : 'desc') .", ";
        }
    }

    $sOrder = substr_replace( $sOrder, "", -2 );
    if ( $sOrder == "ORDER BY" )
    {
        $sOrder = "";
    }
}


/* 
 * Filtering
 * NOTE this does not match the built-in DataTables filtering which does it
 * word by word on any field. It's possible to do here, but concerned about efficiency
 * on very large tables, and MySQL's regex functionality is very limited
 */
$sWhere = "";
if ( isset($_GET['sSearch']) && $_GET['sSearch'] != "" )
{
    $sWhere = "WHERE (";
    for ( $i=0 ; $i<count($aColumns) ; $i++ )
    {
        if ( isset($_GET['bSearchable_'.$i]) && $_GET['bSearchable_'.$i] == "true" )
        {
            $sWhere .= "`".$aColumns[$i]."` LIKE '%".mysql_real_escape_string( $_GET['sSearch'] )."%' OR ";
        }
    }
    $sWhere = substr_replace( $sWhere, "", -3 );
    $sWhere .= ')';
}

/* Individual column filtering */
for ( $i=0 ; $i<count($aColumns) ; $i++ )
{
    if ( isset($_GET['bSearchable_'.$i]) && $_GET['bSearchable_'.$i] == "true" && $_GET['sSearch_'.$i] != '' )
    {
        if ( $sWhere == "" )
        {
            $sWhere = "WHERE ";
        }
        else
        {
            $sWhere .= " AND ";
        }
        $sWhere .= "`".$aColumns[$i]."` LIKE '%".mysql_real_escape_string($_GET['sSearch_'.$i])."%' ";
    }
}


/*
 * SQL queries
 * Get data to display
 */
$sQuery = "
    SELECT SQL_CALC_FOUND_ROWS `".str_replace(" , ", " ", implode("`, `", $aColumns))."`
    FROM   $sTable
    $sWhere
    $sOrder
    $sLimit
    ";
$rResult = mysql_query( $sQuery, $gaSql['link'] ) or fatal_error( 'MySQL Error1: ' . mysql_errno() . " " .mysql_error() );

/* Data set length after filtering */
$sQuery = "
    SELECT FOUND_ROWS()
";
$rResultFilterTotal = mysql_query( $sQuery, $gaSql['link'] ) or fatal_error( 'MySQL Error2: ' . mysql_errno() . " " .mysql_error()  );
$aResultFilterTotal = mysql_fetch_array($rResultFilterTotal);
$iFilteredTotal = $aResultFilterTotal[0];

/* Total data set length */
$sQuery = "
    SELECT COUNT(`".$sIndexColumn."`)
    FROM   $sTable
";
$rResultTotal = mysql_query( $sQuery, $gaSql['link'] ) or fatal_error( 'MySQL Error3: ' . mysql_errno()  . " " .mysql_error() );
$aResultTotal = mysql_fetch_array($rResultTotal);
$iTotal = $aResultTotal[0];


/*
 * Output
 */
$output = array(
    "sEcho" => intval($_GET['sEcho']),
    "iTotalRecords" => $iTotal,
    "iTotalDisplayRecords" => $iFilteredTotal,
    "aaData" => array()
);

while ( $aRow = mysql_fetch_array( $rResult ) )
{
    $row = array();
    for ( $i=0 ; $i<count($aColumns) ; $i++ )
    {
        if ( $aColumns[$i] == "version" )
        {
            /* Special output formatting for 'version' column */
            $row[] = ($aRow[ $aColumns[$i] ]=="0") ? '-' : $aRow[ $aColumns[$i] ];
        }
        else if ( $aColumns[$i] != ' ' )
        {
            /* General output */
            $row[] = $aRow[ $aColumns[$i] ];
        }
    }
    $output['aaData'][] = $row;
}

echo json_encode( $output );
```

?>

here is the html : I am pasting only the

```
 <table cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" border="0" class="display" id="example">
    <thead>
      <tr>
        <th>f_name</th>
        <th>l_name</th>
        <th>email</th>
    <th>active</th>
         <th>create_date</th>   

      </tr>
    </thead>
  <tfoot>
      <tr>
        <th>f_name</th>
        <th>l_name</th>
        <th>email</th>
    <th>active</th>
         <th>create_date</th>
      </tr>
    </tfoot>
  </table>
```

Comment: from the server.php you have to return json data using for example [json_encode()](http://php.net/manual/ru/function.json-encode.php) function. Also look to the [example](https://datatables.net/release-datatables/examples/data_sources/server_side.html) from documentation.

Comment: @BuDen: 
Thanks for the prompt reply. I have included my server.php in the edit section

Comment: It would be more interesting to see the actual `JSON`

Comment: have tou tried to use "mDataProp" instead of "mData" in settings?

Comment: @BuDen:
It doesnt work. I am getting the same error.. How do I see the actual JSON?

Comment: just navigate to your server.php url or check server.php in "Network" tab if you using Chrome or Firefox and watch to the response.

Comment: @BuDen:
Thanks for the patience. I ran the server.php in the chrome browser. In the Network tab it shows nothing. I had tried this.
It says no request captured as the warning

Comment: Can you add the actual error message ?

Comment: @Maz: When I run my file no data is displayed. I get the foll. error message when I run my page in the localhost:

DatTables warning(table id = 'example' : DataTables warning:JSON data from server could not be parsed. This is caused by JSON formatting error

No data is loaded in the table

Comment: Does your original sql returns any data ? `var_dump($output)` in your php file. You can also echo your sql query just to check if the query is alright.

Comment: @ davidkonrad:
I am new to this just started yday. I do not know how to get JSON. I tried what BuDen suggested but I am not getting anything in the Network tab.. See my replis above

Comment: @Maz:
I used var_dump($output) and also tried echoing the query in the server.php n ran it in the browser. It is only displaying the entire code in the browser nd nothing else..

Comment: @Seeya K, call your server.php in your browser, eg localhost/server.php or whatever the path is - and update the answer with the output.

Comment: @davidkonrad:
Here is the error that I get. I am using the server.php file from the datatables.net website from the example. I have only changed the database,table n the host names:

Notice: Undefined index: sEcho in C:\xampp\htdocs\datatabletest\server.php on line 64

Notice: Undefined variable: iTotal in C:\xampp\htdocs\datatabletest\server.php on line 65

Notice: Undefined variable: iFilteredTotal in C:\xampp\htdocs\datatabletest\server.php on line 66

Notice: Undefined variable: sQuery in C:\xampp\htdocs\datatabletest\server.php on line 90

Comment: What do you mean by entire code ? What is the output of your var_dump ? Your sql is working ? Do you have valid rows coming from db ?

Comment: @Maz: Here is the result of var_dump:
array(4) { ["sEcho"]=> int(0) ["iTotalRecords"]=> NULL ["iTotalDisplayRecords"]=> NULL ["aaData"]=> array(622) { [0]=> array(5) { [0]=> string(4) "MARY" [1]=> string(5) "SMITH" [2]=> string(29) "MARY.SMITH@sakilacustomer.org" [3]=> string(1) "1" [4]=> string(19) "2006-02-14 22:04:36" } [1]=> array(5) { [0]=> string(8) "PATRICIA" [1]=> string(7) "JOHNSON" [2]=> string(35) 

Comes from db. The data from db is huge so I have pasted few lines that got displayed when I use var_dump

Comment: The query is printed when I tried printing it. So there is no problem with the query

Comment: great; seems you have some data and your sql is correct. And from your previous answer to @davidkonrad you don't have anything echo'ed when you echo the json_encoded value. Am I correct ? If so; then you may want to check whether your json_ecode works.

You need to also add `error_reporting(E_ALL ^ E_NOTICE);` in the beginning of your php script. If you have notice echo'ed in your page  then you will get invalid json for your javascript to parse.

Comment: You appearently have a lot of bugs in your code - this has nothing to do with datatables. No offense! And what is the point with aaData as array, and later on aaData[] = another array? That will datatables not like :)

Comment: @davidkonrad:
None offenses taken. I had used the same file which they provided online on the net

Comment: @Maz:
I am getting the foll. error now:
DatTables warning(table id = 'example' : Requested unknown parameter "first_name" from the data source for row 0

In my file.php where I use marray:first_name; 

I get the above mentioned error.

Comment: You haven't change the database column in this array? `$aColumns = array( 'first_name', 'last_name', 'email', 'active', 'create_date' );` according to your table ? Each field should be following your table entity :)

Post your mysql table schema too :)

Comment: Here is :
$aColumns = array( 'first_name', 'last_name', 'email', 'active', 'create_date' );
and here is schema:
CREATE TABLE `customer` (
  `customer_id` smallint(5) unsigned NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `store_id` tinyint(3) unsigned NOT NULL,
  `first_name` varchar(45) NOT NULL,
  `last_name` varchar(45) NOT NULL,
  `email` varchar(50) DEFAULT NULL,
  `address_id` smallint(5) unsigned NOT NULL,
  `active` tinyint(1) NOT NULL DEFAULT '1',
  `create_date` datetime NOT NULL,
  `last_update` timestamp NOT NULL DEFAULT CURRENT_TIMESTAMP ON UPDATE CURRENT_TIMESTAMP,
  PRIMARY KEY (`customer_id`),
);

Comment: @Maz:
here is my file.php
$(document).ready(function() {
    var oTable = $('#example').dataTable( {
        "bProcessing": true,
        "sAjaxSource": "server.php",
        "aoColumns": [
   { "mData": "first_name" },
            { "mData": "first_name" },
            { "mData": "last_name" },
            { "mData": "email" },
   { "mData": "active_date" }
            
        ]
  } );
} );

Comment: Can you edit your question and add your html too ?

Comment: @Maz:
I have included the html in the ques

Comment: @Maz: I do not know how to add data retrived into the table

Comment: Try this:

`$(document).ready(function() {
var oTable = $('#example').dataTable( {
    "bProcessing": true,
    "bServerSide": true,
    "sAjaxSource": "server.php"
   } );
 } );`

Comment: @Maz:
Thanks. That works. But only problem is it gives foll. error before displaying data:
DatTables warning(table id = 'example' :
Requested unknown parameter '5' from the data source for row 0

Comment: @Maz: Please make ur prev comment as answer so I can accept it.. And thanks a lot for so much patience n help :)

Comment: Works: you can view the result in your table ? It is easy to debug if you can provide a link (after uploading your content).

Comment: @Maz:
Thanks a ton. I have accepted yoour answer.
Now I was trying to add/update and delete records. But doesnt seem to work.
Please go through this link:
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18846999/add-update-and-delete-records-of-database-using-jquery-datatables
I have posted my query there

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
    $(document).ready(function() { 
      var oTable = $('#example').dataTable( { 
       "bProcessing": true, 
       "bServerSide": true, 
       "sAjaxSource": "server.php" 
     } ); 
   } );
```

You were missing `"bServerSide": true`.