# Add,Update and delete records of database using jquery datatables

Tags: php, jquery, datatables

I amusing the following code to display data from database using jquery datatables

```
    $(document).ready(function() { 
    var oTable = $('#example').dataTable( {
     "bProcessing": true,
     "bServerSide": true,
     "sAjaxSource": "server.php" }
     ); 
     } );
```

The above code displays data in the table

```
 <table cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" border="0" class="display" id="example">
    <thead>
      <tr>
        <th>first name</th>
        <th>last name</th>
        <th>email</th>


      </tr>
    </thead>

    <tfoot>
      <tr>
        <th>first name</th>
        <th>last name</th>
        <th>email</th>
      </tr>
    </tfoot>
  </table>
```

Now I want to add/update and delete data.How do I do that?

I tried

```
 $(document).ready(function() { 
    var oTable = $('#example').dataTable.makeEditable( {
     "bProcessing": true,
     "bServerSide": true,
     "sAjaxSource": "server.php" }
     ); 
     } );
```

but the data doesnt show up. How should I go about?

EDIT:

Here is the file server.php that I used. server.php is just a name that I have given to the file
server.php

```
 <?php
error_reporting(E_ALL ^ E_NOTICE); 
/* * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * *
 * Easy set variables
 */

/* Array of database columns which should be read and sent back to DataTables. Use a space where
 * you want to insert a non-database field (for example a counter or static image)
 */
$aColumns = array( 'first_name', 'last_name', 'email' );

/* Indexed column (used for fast and accurate table cardinality) */
$sIndexColumn = "customer_id";

/* DB table to use */
$sTable = "customer";

/* Database connection information */
$gaSql['user']       = "root";
$gaSql['password']   = "";
$gaSql['db']         = "test";
$gaSql['server']     = "localhost";

/* REMOVE THIS LINE (it just includes my SQL connection user/pass) */
//include( $_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT']."/datatables/mysql.php" );


/* * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * *
 * If you just want to use the basic configuration for DataTables with PHP server-side, there is
 * no need to edit below this line
 */

/* 
 * Local functions
 */
function fatal_error ( $sErrorMessage = '' )
{
    header( $_SERVER['SERVER_PROTOCOL'] .' 500 Internal Server Error' );
    die( $sErrorMessage );
}


/* 
 * MySQL connection
 */
if ( ! $gaSql['link'] = mysql_connect( $gaSql['server'], $gaSql['user'], $gaSql['password']  ) )
{
    fatal_error( 'Could not open connection to server' );
}

if ( ! mysql_select_db( $gaSql['db'], $gaSql['link'] ) )
{
    fatal_error( 'Could not select database ' );
}

$query = "select * from customer";
$rResult = mysql_query($query,$gaSql['link']);

/* 
 * Paging
 */
$sLimit = "";
if ( isset( $_GET['iDisplayStart'] ) && $_GET['iDisplayLength'] != '-1' )
{
    $sLimit = "LIMIT ".intval( $_GET['iDisplayStart'] ).", ".
        intval( $_GET['iDisplayLength'] );
}


/*
 * Ordering
 */
$sOrder = "";
if ( isset( $_GET['iSortCol_0'] ) )
{
    $sOrder = "ORDER BY  ";
    for ( $i=0 ; $i<intval( $_GET['iSortingCols'] ) ; $i++ )
    {
        if ( $_GET[ 'bSortable_'.intval($_GET['iSortCol_'.$i]) ] == "true" )
        {
            $sOrder .= "`".$aColumns[ intval( $_GET['iSortCol_'.$i] ) ]."` ".
                ($_GET['sSortDir_'.$i]==='asc' ? 'asc' : 'desc') .", ";
        }
    }

    $sOrder = substr_replace( $sOrder, "", -2 );
    if ( $sOrder == "ORDER BY" )
    {
        $sOrder = "";
    }
}


/* 
 * Filtering
 * NOTE this does not match the built-in DataTables filtering which does it
 * word by word on any field. It's possible to do here, but concerned about efficiency
 * on very large tables, and MySQL's regex functionality is very limited
 */
$sWhere = "";
if ( isset($_GET['sSearch']) && $_GET['sSearch'] != "" )
{
    $sWhere = "WHERE (";
    for ( $i=0 ; $i<count($aColumns) ; $i++ )
    {
        if ( isset($_GET['bSearchable_'.$i]) && $_GET['bSearchable_'.$i] == "true" )
        {
            $sWhere .= "`".$aColumns[$i]."` LIKE '%".mysql_real_escape_string( $_GET['sSearch'] )."%' OR ";
        }
    }
    $sWhere = substr_replace( $sWhere, "", -3 );
    $sWhere .= ')';
}

/* Individual column filtering */
for ( $i=0 ; $i<count($aColumns) ; $i++ )
{
    if ( isset($_GET['bSearchable_'.$i]) && $_GET['bSearchable_'.$i] == "true" && $_GET['sSearch_'.$i] != '' )
    {
        if ( $sWhere == "" )
        {
            $sWhere = "WHERE ";
        }
        else
        {
            $sWhere .= " AND ";
        }
        $sWhere .= "`".$aColumns[$i]."` LIKE '%".mysql_real_escape_string($_GET['sSearch_'.$i])."%' ";
    }
}


/*
 * SQL queries
 * Get data to display
 */
$sQuery = "
    SELECT SQL_CALC_FOUND_ROWS `".str_replace(" , ", " ", implode("`, `", $aColumns))."`
    FROM   $sTable
    $sWhere
    $sOrder
    $sLimit
    ";
$rResult = mysql_query( $sQuery, $gaSql['link'] ) or fatal_error( 'MySQL Error1: ' . mysql_errno() . " " .mysql_error() );

/* Data set length after filtering */
$sQuery = "
    SELECT FOUND_ROWS()
";
$rResultFilterTotal = mysql_query( $sQuery, $gaSql['link'] ) or fatal_error( 'MySQL Error2: ' . mysql_errno() . " " .mysql_error()  );
$aResultFilterTotal = mysql_fetch_array($rResultFilterTotal);
$iFilteredTotal = $aResultFilterTotal[0];

/* Total data set length */
$sQuery = "
    SELECT COUNT(`".$sIndexColumn."`)
    FROM   $sTable
";
$rResultTotal = mysql_query( $sQuery, $gaSql['link'] ) or fatal_error( 'MySQL Error3: ' . mysql_errno()  . " " .mysql_error() );
$aResultTotal = mysql_fetch_array($rResultTotal);
$iTotal = $aResultTotal[0];
//echo $sQuery;
//exit;



/*
 * Output
 */
$output = array(
    "sEcho" => intval($_GET['sEcho']),
    "iTotalRecords" => $iTotal,
    "iTotalDisplayRecords" => $iFilteredTotal,
    "aaData" => array()
);

while ( $aRow = mysql_fetch_array( $rResult ) )
{
    $row = array();
    for ( $i=0 ; $i<count($aColumns) ; $i++ )
    {
        if ( $aColumns[$i] == "email" )
        {
            /* Special output formatting for 'version' column */
            $row[] = ($aRow[ $aColumns[$i] ]=="0") ? '-' : $aRow[ $aColumns[$i] ];
        }
        else if ( $aColumns[$i] != ' ' )
        {
            /* General output */
            $row[] = $aRow[ $aColumns[$i] ];
        }
    }
    $output['aaData'][] = $row;
}
//echo Json($output, JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);


//var_dump($output);
//exit;
echo json_encode( $output );
 ?>
```

Answer (score 4):

**Add**
http://datatables.net/examples/api/add_row.html

**Inline Editing Example**
http://datatables.net/blog/Inline_editing

**Delete**
http://datatables.net/examples/api/select_single_row.html

I would recommend googling your exact question and just adding "jQuery Datatable" to the end of your search.  I have worked with this plugin quite a bit and it seems the community around this plugin is very good.

Comment: Thanks for the links.. I am following http://datatables.net/blog/Inline_editing and it is useful. But have a look at the code I gave. I am calling data and then displaying without using tbody. but in the above link,they are using tbody and have all the edit/delete buttons there. how do i implement them in my code since my approach is diferent?

Comment: is the server.php file publicly accessible?

Comment: I have edited the ques and added server.php file. H ave a look at it

Comment: Sorry, I guess what I was looking for the response from the server.  See this page for the example https://datatables.net/release-datatables/examples/data_sources/server_side.html

Answer (score 1):

DataTable has no edit options built in, but You can do it by connecting it with jEditable jQuery plugin, as described here:
http://datatables.net/examples/api/editable.html

Also there is an ready solution right here: http://code.google.com/p/jquery-datatables-editable/